# Recode A String Variable

Tags: string, stata, recode

```
input VAR1 VAR2
A1 1
A2 0
A3 1
A4 1
A5 1
A6 1
A7 1
A8 1
A9 1
A10 1
A15 1
B7 0
A1 0
A16 1
A17 1
A18 1
A19 1
A20 0
A21 1
end
```

Say you have data such as the ones shown. I have `VAR1` and wish to create from it `VAR2` which takes values 1 if `VAR1` contains at the beginning: A1, A3-A10, A15-A19, A21 or if not then it is zero. I believe for this you can use `strpos(VAR1)` but is it possible to say for example: `strpos(VAR1, "A1, A3/A10, A15/A19, A21")` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works if you have a small number of strings of interest. You may need an alternate approach if you are searching for a larger number of strings, where writing out the ranges of strings (e.g. A3-A10) is unfeasible.

```
clear
input str3 VAR1 VAR2
A1 1
A2 0
A3 1
A4 1
A5 1
A6 1
A7 1
A8 1
A9 1
A10 1
A15 1
B7 0
A1 1
A16 1
A17 1
A18 1
A19 1
A20 0
A21 1
end

gen wanted = 0

local mystrings = "A1 A3 A4 A5 A6 A7 A8 A9 A10 A15 A16 A17 A18 A19 A21"

foreach string in `mystrings' {
    replace wanted = 1 if strpos(VAR1, "`string'") == 1
}

assert wanted == VAR2
```

Note that in your example input, the second occurrence of A1 had a value of 0 but should have a value of 1 according to your post.

Here is a more generalisable solution for larger ranges of strings:

```
gen     A = 0
replace A = 1 if strpos(VAR1,"A") == 1

gen newvar = substr(VAR1,2,.)
destring newvar, replace

gen wanted = 0
replace wanted = 1 if A == 1 & (inlist(newvar,1,21) | inrange(newvar,3,10) | inrange(newvar,15,19))

assert wanted == VAR2
```

Comment: thank you so much this is great. But what if say I have to code A01 through A55 and A59 through A101 was '1' ? Is it a possibility in Stata to just say: "A01/A55 | A59/A101" ? Instead of writing each one separately? Do you have any advice when the ranges of strings is really large?

Comment: If all the strings begin with a single letter, e.g. A, I would suggest using the `substr` function generate a new variable that contains the same string but without the first letter (and so it only contains numbers), then convert that string to numeric using `destring` and select observations using something like `replace wanted = 1 if inrange(newvar,59,101)`. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: thank you very much but the problem is that in the variable 'VAR1' some of the strings start with 'A' but not all of them, some start with 'B', 'C' etc

Comment: That shouldn't matter. I'll edit my answer with some example code.

Comment: thank you so much. One other question is, is it possible to split the variable 'VAR1' into 'VARA' and 'VARB' where 'VARA' is the first character from 'VAR1' and 'VARB' is all but the first character from 'VAR1'? I think this can provide another solution!

Comment: `gen VARA = substr(VAR1, 1, 1)` and `gen VARB = substr(VAR1, 2, .)`

Comment: @Cybernike that is perfect thank you so much. my final question, is it possible to split the alpha characters into one variable and the numeric characters into a separate variable?

Comment: @NickCox thank you so much. my final question, is it possible to split the alpha characters into one variable and the numeric characters into a separate variable?

Comment: You're cross-posting at Statalist, That's not good practice without telling people about it. Also, please don't ask new questions in comments.